# how to substitute values for characters in a equation

Tags: java, string, equations

I have a equation a+b-c*d. i am reading the values of a, b,c,d from a different file, i have them stored in a double array.

how do i replace the a/b/c/d with the numerical value from the array?
I have tried this,

```
String l2; //getting the equation string in this from other part of the code. 
//assume a+b-c*d

Double[] secondOperators = new Double[4];
public String getSecondString()
{ 
    l2 = l2.replace("a",toString(secondOperators[0]));
    l2 = l2.replace("b",toString(secondOperators[1]));
    l2 = l2.replace("c",toString(secondOperators[2]));
    l2 = l2.replace("d",toString(secondOperators[3]));  
    return l2;      
}
```

The result was a compile time error

error: method toString in class Object cannot be applied to given types;

```
l2 = l2.replace("a",toString(secondOperators[0]));
                        ^
```

required: no arguments

found: Double

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: and the result was...?

Comment: @JBNizet edited the question with the error

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.valueOf(secondOperators[0])` instead of `toString(secondOperators[0])`

**Edit :**

```
public static String getSecondString()
{ 
    String l2="a+b-c*d";
    Double[] secondOperators = {22.03,334.34,34.57,231.98};
    l2 = l2.replace("a",String.valueOf(secondOperators[0]));
    l2 = l2.replace("b",String.valueOf(secondOperators[1]));
    l2 = l2.replace("c",String.valueOf(secondOperators[2]));
    l2 = l2.replace("d",String.valueOf(secondOperators[3]));  
    return l2;      
}
```

Comment: no suitable method found for replace(char,String)

  l1 = l1.replace('a',String.valueOf(firstOperators[1]));

         ^
    method String.replace(char,char) is not applicable

      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to char)

    method String.replace(CharSequence,CharSequence) is not applicable

      (argument mismatch; char cannot be converted to CharSequence)

Comment: Why you have changed your `"a"` with `'a'`, you cant use `replace` with `one char` and `one string`. Read `String JavaDoc` and get more idea.See my edited answer , Its working.

Comment: Why?  Upvotes are for questions that are likely to be useful to someone else.  Your question isn't, I'm afraid.